# DateTime ParseExact different behaviour on other server

Tags: c#, windows, datetime-format

I have a piece of code that crashes on my test server and not on my development server. I have 2 Windows 2012R2 Servers for dev and test. Both on same patch level, same .NET FrameWork version. Both have the same regional settings (Dutch) for current users and system local. This Dutch setting has the - as the date seperator. The following code snippet works on the dev server but crashes on the test server. I added the snippet with 2 lines of code in a console app and then I can reproducte the error.

The piece of code (simplified for demo console app) is:

```
        string date = "28/02/2017";
        DateTime dateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

So this works on my dev server and crashed on test
I get this exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a vali
d DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInf
o dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provid
er)
```

When I change the code to

```
        string date = "28/02/2017";
        DateTime dateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It works on both servers. When I output the CurrentCultue and CurrentUiCulture in the console app they are the same on both servers.

Any ideas what could go wrong on my test server? When I pass null in the ParseExact method I would expect that the code would also crash on my dev server because the CurrentCulture should then be used and then the date seperator / should cause an error.

Regards
Danny

Comment: *crashes on the test server* what does that mean? What exception do you get?

Comment: you should specify culture for parsing dates anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` specifies that you want to use the current-culture instead, as opposed to passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If provider is `null`, the `CultureInfo` object that corresponds to the
>   current culture is used.

The `/` has a special meaning in parsing datetimes. They will be replaced with the currect culture's `DateSeparator`. [(The "/" custom format specifier)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#The)

You could also mask them:

```
DateTime dateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", null);
```

Comment: This works indeed. But how is it possible that on my first server it works without the '' and on my second server it causes an exception even though the have the same culture settings?

Comment: @DannyH: I don't know. Either the test was different or the culture settings weren't the same even if you say they are. Look at the regional settings of the computers. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/08/16/how-to-change-regional-settings-for-all-users-on-a-computer/

Comment: When I pass the format "dd/MM/yyyy" when I do a DateTime to string the / has no special meaning? That works fine.

Comment: @DannyH: if you use `DateTime.ToString` nothing needs to be parsed, so there is no exception. But it will also replace `/` with the actual `DateSeparator` of the current culture (if you don't pass `InvariantCulture` as second parameter to `ToString`). Here in germany f.e. `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` returns `10.03.2017`.

Answer (score 1):

The `/` characters is not interpreted literally in date format strings. It is get substituted with date separator according to the used format provider.

You need to enclose the `/` in single quotes to make it a literal character in the format string:

```
"dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"
```